# Using variable with sed in Shell Script

Tags: shell, sed

I'm writing a shell script to edit
 Change-Set attributes of aegis. The
 command I'm using is:

> ```
> aegis -Change_Attributes -Edit
> ```

which opens up a vi editor to carry
 out the changes. I want to do a search
 and replace:

> ```
> s/brief_description \= \"none\"\;/brief_description \=
> ```
>
> \"test\"/g

Can I pass these directly to the open
 vi instance via the script without
 typing in any of it? I want to save
 the document (:wq) after editing it.

P.S. The file is a temporary file
 created when executing the command so
 I don't know the original path

**Edit:** I could used sed in this case:

> ```
> sed -e 's/brief_description\ \=\ \"none\"\;/brief_description\ \=\
> ```
>
> \"test\"\;/g'

The solution (inelegant hack??) would
 be to "cat" the output from aegis
 (setenv VISUAL cat), modify the out
 put stream with the above command and
 save it to a temp file, and use :

> ```
> aegis -change_attributes -file <temp file>
> ```

**EDIT2:** I've almost got it to work. But there's a problem with the way I use `sed`

I have the following line in my script:

```
sed -i 's/brief_description\ \=\ \"none\"\;/brief_description\ \=\ \"${DESC}\"\;/g' temp_next.txt
```

But the $DESC variable does not evaluate to its value and the out put is given as:

> brief_description = "${DESC}";

How can I pass DESC to sed that it would evaluate to it's actual value?

**EDIT3:**

Using

```
sed -i 's%brief_description\ \=\ \"none\"\;%brief_description\ \=\ \"'"$DESC"'\"\;%g' temp_next.txt
```

worked. I replace the normal delimiter (/) with % and put the environment variable in double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to know the path - the aegis app will supply that. You need to change the environment variable that specifies what editor aegis uses to point at a script, and in that script use the [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html) stream editor to perform your edits.

**Edit:** Regarding your variable name expansion problem, change the set of single quotes enclosing the whole sed substitution expression to double quotes. Variable substitution is turned off by single quotes.

Comment: If I use cat and modify the output with sed, would the changes get persisted to the file?

Comment: No, you have to redirect the output of sed somewhere, in this case to  a temporary file. Then when the edit is done, delete the original and rename the temporary.

Comment: If you use GNU sed, you can use the -i flag to edit the file in place.

Comment: When I use double quotes:
//sed -i "s/brief_description\ \=\ \"none\"\;/$DESC/g"
I get an error saying //Unmatched ".// I tried several other approaches:
//sed -i 's/brief_description\ \=\ \"none\"\;/'"$DESC'"/g'//
//sed -i 's%brief_description\ \=\ \"none\"\;%'"$DESC'"%g'//

but none of these seem to work. I'm working with csh not bash so this might be a problem with that

Comment: csh was never designed fpr writing scripts with - if you haven't got bash, use sh instead

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the desired command in via the -c option then vi will execute the command immediately after starting the edit session, e.g.

```
vi -c 's/brief_description \= \"none\"\;/brief_description \= \"test\"/g' my_file
```

Oops. I forgot to say that the command is interpreted as an "ex" command, i.e. at the colon, so the command you've provided should work.

HTH

cheers,

Comment: Yes. That was what I was looking for. Unfortunately I don't open the vi session so I can't pass any command line options. I've resorted to using cat instead

Comment: If you really want to use vi, you can do it - just use it instead of sed in the script I suggested. I think the use of sed is better though - I don't see it as inellegant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that vanilla vi will do this, although vim might be able to this under control of a custom .vimrc.  A better way would be to do the changes with sed and then open vi on the result.